# Can postfix forward all outbound email to a relayhost except for local user-to-user email?

Tags: cron, localhost, postfix, fetchmail

On my home Ubuntu box, postfix is configured to relay all outgoing email to `outgoing.verizon.net`. Unfortunately this includes local user-to-user email (e.g., from local cron jobs to me, or from me to myself) which should not need to travel off-machine. Is there a way to tweak my configuration (below) so local email is delivered without leaving my machine?

Note: I don't run a mail server (on port 25) but rather run fetchmail every five minutes to download from an IMAP server.

main.cf:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mycomputer.example.com
masquerade_domains = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [outgoing.verizon.net]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix will only relay `non-local mails` to the host specified in the `relayhost`. To consider a domain local; the domain has to be listed under `mydestination` parameter. So listing `example.com` under `mydestination` should help you to fix this issue.

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#...
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost, example.com
#...
```

Ref: [Postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)

```
relayhost (default: empty)

The next-hop destination of non-local mail; overrides non-local domains in 
recipient addresses. This information is overruled with relay_transport, 
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps, default_transport, 
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps and with the transport(5) table.
```

Comment: Hmm... With my posted configuration, username@localhost gets forwarded to the relayhost. If your analysis is correct, shouldn't username@localhost be handled entirely locally because "localhost" is listed in mydestination?

Comment: Can u post the maillog generated by postfix for such a mail?

Comment: Ah, I was incorrect. username@localhost indeed gets delivered locally. However, mail to just "username" (e.g., "echo foo | /usr/bin/mail username") gets delivered as if I had emailed username@blazemonger.com.

Comment: Then I guess ur `myorigin` has `blazemonger.com`. Add `blazemonger.com` to mydestination to treat it local.